# Token trees in macros (processing argument lists)

Tags: macros, rust

Currently the only way to add extension methods to a type in another module (even if this module is in a submodule) is to define a new trait and implement it for the type. This is very unwieldy, however, as the number of methods becomes large:

```
trait Ops {
    fn parse_list_item(&self, current_item: ListItemInfo) 
        -> ParseResult<(Document, ListItemInfo)>;
    fn parse_list_item_content(&self) -> ParseResult<Document>;
}

impl<'a> Ops for MarkdownParser<'a> {
    fn parse_list_item(&self, current_item: ListItemInfo) 
            -> ParseResult<(Document, ListItemInfo)> {
        // ...
    }

    fn parse_list_item_content(&self) -> ParseResult<Document> {
        // ...
    }
}
```

You have to write method signature twice. If it changes, you also have to update it in multiple places. It also adds a lot of noise.

I though that macros would help, but I don't know how to write a correct `macro_rules!` pattern for argument lists in functions. Here is what I have so far:

```
#![feature(macro_rules)]

struct Foo;

macro_rules! ops (
    ($(fn $name:ident($($args:tt)*) -> $ret:ty $body:block)+) => (
        trait Ops {
            $(fn $name($($args)*) -> $ret;)+
        }

        impl Ops for Foo {
            $(fn $name($($args)*) -> $ret $body)+
        }
    )
)

mod ops {
    ops! {
        fn method1(&self) -> int {
            10
        }

        fn method2(&self, i: int) -> () {
            println!("{}", i + self.method1());
        }
    }

    pub fn run_test() {
        Foo.method2(22);
    }
}

fn main() {
    ops::run_test();
}
```

It fails with rather nasty message:

```
/tmp/rs/ops/src/main.rs:8:27: 8:31 error: expected type, found token INTERPOLATED(NtTT(ptr::P<ast::TokenTree>{ptr: box TTTok(codemap::Span{lo: codemap::BytePos(337u32), hi: codemap::BytePos(338u32), expn_id: codemap::ExpnId(4294967295u32)}, BINOP(AND))}))
/tmp/rs/ops/src/main.rs:8             $(fn $name($($args)*) -> $ret;)+
                                                    ^~~~
```

It probably deserves a bug report as the error message is quite intimidating, however, I don't see another way to pass arguments as is. It seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/9364), however, I hope there is a workaround like 
[in this case](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/15587#issuecomment-58770911).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Firstly, it needs to be `$($args:tt),*`, like [so](http://is.gd/CPPBRA). Not sure why `&self` doesn't match `tt` though

Comment: @Manishearth, I took `$($args:tt)*` from formatting macros. Even though it has comma-separated arguments, it still has a pattern without a comma.

Comment: Did you solve this? It seems that a `tt` can't capture this. I can't find the definition of a "token tree".

Comment: This works fine in Rust 1.74.0 (after replacing `int` with `i32` and `Foo` with `super::Foo`): https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7984bad17d02c85fff59858acef28860